# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

When I run a JAVA program(can not new HTable) under the Eclipse IDE, i got following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeperKeeperException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:154)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:132)
at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class HBaseConnector {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable table = new HTable(config, "myLittleHBaseTable");
    ...
}

--------------
used jar files:
hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.3.0.jar
zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.3.0-tests.jar
lf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
commons-configuration-1.9.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
hadoop-core-0.20.0.jar
```

Where is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I fixed this by editing the file "/usr/local/hbase-0.94.1/conf/hbase-env.sh" and adding the element "export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase-0.94.1/lib".

The zookeeper JAR is located in the HBase installation at "/usr/local/hbase-0.94.1/lib".

Answer (score 0):

Just include the zookeeper jar file in your build path located in HBASE.
It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your class might not get access via your code try using distributed cache and load the jar files, use the link to set the configurations : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html