# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration compiling using javac

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, classnotfound

I'm a beginner in Hadoop and MapReduce. After I installed Hadoop on my Ubuntu VM, I tried some starter examples like Wordcount and Anagram.

I would like to do an `Apriori on MapReduce`. I found this one on Sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/p/apriorimapred/wiki/Home/).

After I download and installed some required components such as `HBase` and `Log4j` (though I have problems installing log4j so I chose to disable them by setting the level to off),

I struggle with the problem

```
"Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration" -- as in the picture. (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51053996/Pics/hadoop%20classnotfound.jpg)
```

It happens every time I would like to run the jar file.
The steps I take are

```
1. javac -cp "$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-common-2.0.0-alpha.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.2-alpha.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/commons-configuration-1.10/*:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/hbase-0.94.8.jar" apriori.java

2. jar -cvf apriori.jar -C . .

3. $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /home/hduser/yarn/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/apriori.jar apriori /in /out2 /out2c /out2a
```

(The problem happens after I enter the command in step 3)
There is no error shown after I compiled in step 1 (However, I have tried compiling while not including the `"/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/hbase-0.94.8.jar"` and there are around 100 errors -- so I guess the lib works well).

I stick with this problem for around 2 weeks :( and couldn't find any working solutions. I have tried many suggestion I found such as fixing the environment variables, add some lines in `hbase-env.sh`, etc. Here are some that I bookmarked them (but didn't solve mine).

- [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364057/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-hba)
- [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)
- [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150604/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-zookeeper-keeperexceptio)
- https://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/installing-apache-hbase-on-ubuntu-for-standalone-mode/
- http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-HBase-on-Ubuntu

Thank you so much and really appreciated every help,

Spacez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by re-installing Hadoop and HBase with compatible versions (I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 and HBase 0.98.11). Also, adding correct classpaths of the Hadoop and Hbase jars in the hadoop-env.

Answer (score 1):

I was using hbase-098.8-hadoop2 with nutch 2.3.1 (gora 0.6.1) and encountered the same error. It was fixed after I added the following line to `$NUTCH_ROOT/ivy/ivy.xml`:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.hbase" name="hbase-common" rev="0.98.8-hadoop2" conf="*->default" />
```

This is mentioned as a gora bug in the official [Nutch 2](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy `hbase-{vsersion}.jar` from `$HBASE_HOME` to `$HADOOP_HOME/lib`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I try doing so unfortunately the problem still persists :(

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51053996/Pics/hadoop.jpg

Comment: Did you restart you cluster?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, i simply ran:

```
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`~/hbase/bin/hbase classpath`
java  -cp "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:target/<myjar>.jar" <path_to>.<myHBaseClass>
```